# Flex SkinPart is defined as required false. The compiler generates error that it is

Tags: apache-flex, compilation

I have a `s:SkinnableContainer` base class that defines several skin part as `[SkinPart(required="false")]`. This class is being sub-classed by several different classes that also have definitions such as `[SkinPart(required="true")]`. Each sub class has its own skin that implements all the `required=true` skin parts. some of them implements the `required=false` skin part.

The flex compiler randomly generates the following errors:

```
The required skin part '__moduleFactoryInitialized' is missing. ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part '_selectedApplication' is missing.   ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part '_skinClass' is missing. ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part 'initialize' is missing. ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part 'initialize' is missing. ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part 'ux_title' is missing.   ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The required skin part 'ux_titleSignpost' is missing.   ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The skin part type 'components:BooleanButtonBar' must be assignable to 'spark.components:Button'.   ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The skin part type 'components.renderers:StateRenderer' must be assignable to 'spark.components:NumericStepper'.    ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The skin part type 'spark.components:NumericStepper' must be assignable to 'components.renderers:StateRenderer'.    ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The skin part type 'spark.components:NumericStepper' must be assignable to 'spark.components:Label'.    ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
The skin part type 'spark.components:VGroup' must be assignable to 'spark.components.supportClasses:TextBase'.  ThresholdPercentageWidgetSkin.mxml  /am-apm-app-ui/src/main/flex/styles/skins   line 12 Flex Problem
```

For example the `required skin part 'ux_title' is missing` error relates to label which is `required=false`.

In addition, some skin parts that are mentioned are internal. For example - `__moduleFactoryInitialized`, `_skinClass` and `initialize`.

And now to the woodoo part - adding new line in one of the mentioned files, would generate a successful compilation.

I tries cleaning files from unseen special characters.

Any clue why it could happen?

---

I tried you suggested work around - did not work. But I got slightly different error

```
[ERROR] <filename>[13,-1] The skin part type 'spark.components:Label' must b
 e assignable to 'spark.components:Button'.
[ERROR] <filename>:[13,-1] The skin part type 'components.help:SignPost' must
 be assignable to 'spark.components:Button'.
```

and many as the above two examples. Note the [13,-1] row/column pair. The -1 means something internal went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell if you don't show any code. Try to reproduce this behaviour in a minimalist example and post it in your question. Some wild guesses: missing CDATA tag in script block; an exotic character encoding of your files

Comment: agreed-- it would be much easier to help if you have a known failing piece of code that we could run and thereby reproduce the errors

Comment: Hi - you are totally right. Nevertheless, it is a rather large enterprise application (well big...) and it is not feasible to extract code. I will update. Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue.  It only occurred on our CI server.  I tried all available 4.6 compilers on my workstation but could not reproduce the issue with the same code.  As a work around I changed

```
[SkinPart(required="true")]
```

to

```
[SkinPart]
```

for now.  I tried keeping the generated Actionscript to try and locate the problem but I didn't see anything that would cause it.  The reason I tried that was because originally the compiler errors were about variables in my own code being required SkinParts (but in reality were not skin parts at all).   Based on one of the comments on the post I scanned for any non-ascii characters in my code, but there weren't any.